# Fixing "use of unresolved identifier 'addTarget'" while adding func to button click event

Tags: ios, uibutton, addtarget

I've created a UIButton programmatically as shown below:

```
let buttons: [UIButton] = [UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))];
```

Now if I try to add a function to it programmatically like this:

```
[buttons[0] addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

I get an error saying that addTarget is not defined.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Why is this tagged swift?

Comment: Your first line is swift, and your second line is in Objective-C syntax - is this deliberate?

Comment: @ChrisShaw It's not deliberate I just made a silly mistake :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are try to use the Objective-C syntax in swift, this is entirely wrong, use your code as like

```
 buttons.first?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and handle the action as like

```
 @objc func buttonClicked( _ sender: UIButton) {
       print("buttonClicked Action Found")

}
```

Ref : [Apple Document for UIButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton)

Comment: @SrikanthEswaran - dont think so, if you r new in iOS, it will happens always.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are creating `[UIButton]` which is `Array` of `UIButton` and it's not a single Button.

You can not create `Array` of `UIButton` that way. You will need a `for` loop for that and you need to update the `frame` accordingly.

And you can create a single `UIButton` this way:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
```

then you can add it into the `UIView` this way:

```
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Without above line it your button will not show into your screen.

Next if you want to add action to that button you can do it by adding this line in your button code:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and it will need a helper method which will execute when button will click.

```
@objc func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //Perform your action when button is clicked.
}
```

And you also need to apply `backgroundColor` and `setTitle` to the button.

and your final code will look like:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
button.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button)
```